# the dimension and read problem when using DPC++ image arrays

Tags: c++, dpc++

This problem really confuse me. I wanna use DPC++ to read a group of images, so the sycl::image was used ,below are my code.

```
#define N 4   //dimensin
#define M 128 //dimension 
#define C 4   //4 channel
#define L 2   // 2 images
int * host_array3_2 = malloc_host<int>(N*M*C*L, Q);
image im3(host_array3_2, image_channel_order::rgba, image_channel_type::unsigned_int32, range{ M,N,L}); //the image format
```

The kernel code are as follows, I use accessor with image_array tags to  read the data:

```
Q.submit([&](handler &h) {
           auto out = sycl::stream(1024, 1024 * 2, h);
            accessor<int4, 2, access::mode::read, access::target::image_array> acs3(im3, h);//the accessor format
            h.parallel_for(nd_range{ range{ M ,N,L }, range{ N,N,L } }, [=](nd_item<3> it) {
            int idx = it.get_global_linear_id();
                if (idx == 0){
            confuse here:  out << acs3.get_count() << " " << acs3.get_range() << " \n";
                //const auto &ss = acs3[0];    no compile error
        confuse here:  //ss.read(int2(0, 1));         compiler error: "array subscript out of range"  "SYCL kernel cannot call a variadic function"}
            });
        });
```

In addition to the read problem , I found that the range is{128,4,4},
why the third dimension is 4? Isn’t the value of L(2)?

And it seems that the third dimension is only depend on the second dimension, no matter what the L is.  Can anybody answer me?

Answer (score 0):

An interesting phenomenon, under the release compile mode ,it will be ok ,and the output are also different. that's strange